# Counting words within a window & features

Tags: python

I have somewhat complex counting problem. I'm trying to compose a concurrence data frame with rows of words in a corpus and columns these same words PLUS a set of features (e.g plural, singular, past tense, etc).

I've already developed a dictionary of relevant. Each of these words are dictionaries where each key is a word or feature. Like so:

```
WordDict={Word1 :{word1:0, word2:0 ... feature1:0, feature2:0 ...}, Word2 :{word1:0, word2:0 ... feature1:0, feature2:0 ...} ...}
```

I also have a corpus of words (lemmatized):

```
doc=['Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3' ...]
```

I also have a list of lists with tokens and their features:

```
meh=[['Word1', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3'], ['Word2', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3', 'Feature4' ], ['Word3', 'Feature1', 'Feature3']]
```

Ideally what I want is a dictionary to look like this:

```
WordDict={Word1:{word1:0, word2:1 ... feature1:1, feature2:1 ...}, Word2:{word1:1, word2:0 ... feature1:1, feature2:1 ...} ...}
```

Because the words are lemmas, some words will be repeated in `doc`, but in `WordDict` there would be only one entry. Essentially I need to

1. for every top-level key in `WordDict` iterate through `meh`.

   1a. for every feature observed in a list in `meh` for every top-level key, add +1 to the relevant feature count in `WordDict`.
2. for every top-level key in `WordDict` iterate through `doc`

   2a. for every word seen 5 units to the left or right, add +1 to the relevant word count `WordDict`

I've looked into using some sort of ngram window for this:

```
def windower(list, n):
    for count,ele in enumerate(list):
        if count-n < 0:
            window=list[0:count+n]
        else:
            window=list[count-n:count+n]
```

So I think from here to count the word cooccurances I need a way to add occurrences from `window` to the relevant word key in `WordDict`

Hopefully someone can help?

Comment: Trenton-m, this question is a tiny bit different it ask how to incorporate a term-term concurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below code according to your description.

But `2.` and `2a.` feels pretty weird to me. I don't think the code is entirely what you want.

```py
wordDict = {
    "word1": {
        "word1": 0,
        "word2": 0,
        "word3": 0,
        "feature1": 0,
        "feature2": 0,
        "feature3": 0,
    },
    "word2": {
        "word1": 0,
        "word2": 0,
        "word3": 0,
        "feature1": 0,
        "feature2": 0,
        "feature3": 0,
    },
    "word3": {
        "word1": 0,
        "word2": 0,
        "word3": 0,
        "feature1": 0,
        "feature2": 0,
        "feature3": 0,
    },
}

# some will be repeated you say?
doc = ["word1", "word1", "word2", "word3"]

meh = [["word1", "feature2", "feature3"], ["word2", "feature2"], ["word3", "feature1"]]

for word, wf in wordDict.items():

    # 1a starts
    found = False
    for m in meh:
        if m[0] == word:
            found = True

            for f in m[1:]:
                wf[f] += 1

        if found:
            break
    # 1a ends

    # 2a starts
    docLen = len(doc)
    for i, d in enumerate(doc):
        # 5 to the left, excluding itself
        for j in range(max(0, i - 5), i):
            wf[doc[j]] += 1
        # 5 to the right, excluding itself
        for j in range(i + 1, min(i + 6, docLen)):
            wf[doc[j]] += 1
    # 2a ends


print(wordDict)

# {'word1': {'word1': 6, 'word2': 3, 'word3': 3, 'feature1': 0, 'feature2': 1, 'feature3': 1}, 'word2': {'word1': 6, 'word2': 3, 'word3': 3, 'feature1': 0, 'feature2': 1, 'feature3': 0}, 'word3': {'word1': 6, 'word2': 3, 'word3': 3, 'feature1': 1, 'feature2': 0, 'feature3': 0}}
```